# Does the Red Queen's face intentionally evoke Mickey Mouse?

Tags: through-the-looking-glass, alice-in-wonderland-2010, character

When watching Alice Through The Looking Glass the thought came to my mind that the Red Queen's hair is shaped like Mickey Mouse's ears. There is even this spike at the middle, with a large forehead. The head itself is much larger than the body.

Does anybody know if it was made on purpose? Is it a tribute to Mickey of some sort? One of the reasons would be that Mickey is an emblematic character of Disney, the production Studio of the movie.

It is pretty obvious that the primary design goal is to make her head look like a heart. This is not the question here. There can be several design goals. The question is whether there is an easter egg or tribute consisting of adapting this heart-shape hair to evoke Mickey Mouse.

Does anybody knows any interview confirming or denying this?

[image: Red queen in Alice Through the Looking Glass]
[image: Mickey Mouse]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54187/discussion-on-question-by-tom-does-the-red-queens-face-intentionally-evoke-mick).

Answer (score 84):

As with many adaptations of Lewis Carroll, the characters of the Queen of Hearts and the Red Queen have been combined.

Thus her hair is in the shape of a heart. Any resemblance to Mickey Mouse is coincidence.

The [widow's peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow's_peak) is a common appearance, especially for villainous characters, and also makes her face more heart-shaped.

The concept art looks even less like Mickey Mouse.

[image: Sketch by Tim Burton] [image: Sketch by Colleen Atwood]

No, nobody has ever explicitly confirmed nor denied this, for the same reason nobody has explicitly confirmed nor denied whether her hair was intended to look like a pretzel.

Comment: The question is not really if there is a resemblance or not. I was curious if anybody read or heard anything related to that from Burton himself or somebody involved in the movie.

Comment: The fact that concept art looked less like Mickey Mouse can mean the idea came later.

Comment: The answer is still "no". And there is no evidence that it is intentional.

Comment: The question is precisely whether there are evidences. The fact you don't know any doesn't mean it is not the case.

Comment: What will it take for you to accept that the answer is "no"? You're the one who thinks it's based on Mickey Mouse - the burden of proof is on you. All the "evidence" you have presented has been refuted.

Comment: I don't expose it as a fact. I have nothing to prove. I ask if anybody knows something related to that. Maybe it makes sense, maybe it is just my imagination. I will wait and see if anybody has useful information.

Comment: @Tom are you saying you won't be satisfied until someone provides information which agrees with your theory?  He provided a reason for the shape and showed designs to suggest it was only supposed to be a heart.  It's pretty easy to see that at some angles it may look like mickey ears, but this is quite a convincing argument that it is coincidence.  It would be hard to have it look like a heart from every angle.

Comment: I think Disney did this as a sort of opening for a crossover between the Mickey Mouse and Alice in Wonderland universes. Just kidding. Her hair is obviously resembles a heart.

Comment: @Tom You're right that a lack of evidence regarding Mickey is not the same as evidence that he's not related, but nobody's going to make a list of things the Red Queen's hair isn't patterned after. You aren't going to find a quote from the hairstylist saying "her hair was NOT modeled after Mickey, or a bactrian camel, or the Mandelbrot set, or a porpoise's forehead, or..." etc. At some point you just have to accept with a reasonable certainty that there's probably not a connection to Mickey because we can't absolutely know for sure.

Comment: @Tom It's mostly the fact that this is a question-and-answer site, and so the purpose is to find good quality answers to people's questions. It's totally fine to have questions that you may not need an answer for, but I think the whole issue here has resulted from a disconnect between your expectations and the intentions of people providing answers. They've provided good quality answers according to the criteria of the site, and even if it may not be what you're looking for it's the best that people can do.

Comment: @Tom And you're right, maybe the answer will pop up in a documentary some day, at which point somebody can put up an answer with the new information. That's the great thing about this site. But for now this is the best we have.

Comment: You are right, some answers are well documented, I even up-voted some of them because of that. But as you say this is the best we have so far. So let's wait. Thanks everybody for your contribution.

Comment: Please take further conversation about this to chat.  It's a much better forum for extended conversation!

Answer (score 42):

According to hairstylist Terry Baliel, the wig for Helena Bonham-Carter was specifically designed to look like a heart. Any resemblance to the shape of Mickey Mouse's head would appear to be a coincidence, and therefore unintentional.

> **Hair:** “Helena’s look was hard and structured,” says Baliel. “We wanted
>   the wig to be heart-shaped — we built some mesh pads and combed the
>   hair, strand by strand, over that, ending up with curls on top so it
>   almost looks like a bouquet of roses.

Here is a link to the interview where the costumes & hair design for each character are discussed:

http://nypost.com/2010/02/28/how-fashion-and-beauty-visionaries-brought-alice-in-wonderland-to-life/

---

**History:**

With a little more research, we find that both The Queen of Hearts as well as her enemy The Duchess had heads that were roughly heart-shaped due to their headdresses, which are notably Elizabethan in origin. This interpretation of the character goes back to the original 1871 Tenniel illustrations:

[image]

It's important to note that the actual text of the books never describes her head as such, or even gives much of a physical description at all.

Comment: This interview is interesting indeed. And I think there was no doubt the idea was to make it a heart shape. However this is not incompatible with the Mickey Mouse hypothesis. She doesn't deny it nor confirm it.

Comment: @Tom - neither Burton nor Baliel seem to be active on Twitter, but I sent a tweet to what I THINK is Bonham-Carter's account. She probably won't reply, but maybe we'll get lucky.

Comment: @Tom - I'm not sure how "We wanted it to be heart-shaped" is **in any way** compatible with looking like Mickey, since his head is very much *not* heart-shaped.

Comment: @Tom: Tom, please understand and internalize the ideas of "burden of proof" and "proving a negative".

Comment: If I had a proof, I wouldn't ask the question. And I don't have a definitive idea on it, this is why I ask the question. Other comments misinterpret my intentions.

Answer (score 20):

I agree with @OrangeDog that the heart-shaped hair is intended as a reminder that this character is both [the Queen of Hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_Hearts_(Alice's_Adventures_in_Wonderland)) and [the Red Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Queen_(Through_the_Looking-Glass)). However, it might also be an exaggerated version of the hairstyle found on [a famous portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armada_Portrait) of Queen Elizabeth I.

[image: The "Armada Portrait" of Queen Elizabeth I, by an unknown English artist]

This is attested to by [Valli O'Reilly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valli_O'Reilly), an Oscar-winning makeup artist who worked on *Alice in Wonderland*, as reported by [the New York Post](http://nypost.com/2010/02/28/how-fashion-and-beauty-visionaries-brought-alice-in-wonderland-to-life/):

> "Helena [Bonham Carter] took longer because we had to have a prosthetic piece put over her eyebrows," says [Valli] O'Reilly. "Tim [Burton]'s notes to me and Helena were: Bette Davis as Queen Elizabeth, in that 1939 movie where she had red hair and her forehead was really high and the eyebrows might even have been shaved off."

Here's a [short video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8Irm7lZ3DA) and a photograph of Bette Davis from [*The Private Lives of Elizabeth and Essex* (1939)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Private_Lives_of_Elizabeth_and_Essex), which is likely the movie referred to, from [*Stalking the Belle Époque*](http://stalkingthebelleepoque.blogspot.com/2011/04/film-of-week-private-lives-of-elizabeth.html):

[image: Bette Davis as Queen Elizabeth from *The Private Lives of Elizabeth and Essex* (1939)]

Comment: Actually I thought it was not implausible that Mickey Mouse had become so popular because he had a certain regalness.  It is not impossible that he was subconsciously modeled in part after this portrait.

Comment: You're actually more correct than I thought: "Bette Davis as Queen Elizabeth, in that 1939 movie where she had red hair and her forehead was really high and the eyebrows might even have been shaved off."